# How to prove that all solutions to $Ax=b$ are $(x_0 + bv_1 +cv_2)$, where $A$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{N}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

The linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ and is represented by the matrix $A$. A basis for the null space of $A$ consists of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Prove that if a particular solution to $Ax=b$ , for a given $b$, is $x=x_0$, then all the solutions can be expressed as $x_0 + bv_1 + cv_2$.

I can prove that if $x_0$ is a solution, then so is $x_0 +bv_1 + cv_2$, but how do I prove that these are the only solutions? For example, it could be the case that there exists $x=x_1$ such that $x_1 \neq x_0 + bv_1 +cv_2$, but $x_1 + bv_1 + cv_2$ would still be a solution for all $(b,c)$.

Another related question I have is that if I am given the basis vectors for the range space of T, I can set $b = a_1v_1 +a_2v_2 + a_3v_3+\dotsb$ and thus solve for $a_1,a_2,a_3...,$ hence finding a particular solution to Ax=b. But why does this method give me a unique $x$? Should it not give me an answer of the form $x_0 + bv_1 +cv_2$?

Comment: [How to format questions correctly using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hint: If $x$ and $y$ are two solutions, what is $Ax-Ay$?

Comment: Edited. 
Ax - Ay is 0. So Az = 0, where z=x-y 
Z can take any value of the form bv1 +cv2, since it is in the null space of A. Hence the difference between x and y must be some linear combination of v1 and v2. Thus, if I have any solution y, it can be written as x0 + bv1 +cv2, and therefore all the solutions of this equation are of the form x0+bv1 +cv2. Is this correct? Could you answer the second part?

Comment: I remember doing some questions where I was given a matrix which represented a linear transformation, and I had to find all the solutions to Ax=b, for some b. I set b equal to some linear combination of the basis vectors of the range space, and I had a unique solution i.e b = a1v1 +a2v2 +a3v3... was only satisfied for say (a1,a2,a3 ) =(5,7,9), so then the original equation would have a particular solution x=(5,7,9). What I don't understand is why I get this particular value of x0 when I solve for the constants. I could have gotten any other value, and it would still satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

REVISED: Assume that the rank of $A$ is $N-2$, that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal and that $Av_1=Av_2=\mathbf0$, i.e the column vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ span the null space of $A$. Now augment $A$ with rows $v_1^T$ and $v_2^T$ such that 
$$
A_0=\begin{bmatrix}
        A \\
        v_1^T \\
        v_2^T \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
making $A_0$ square and with a rank of $N$.
Also argument $b$ with two zeros such that 
$$
b_0=\begin{bmatrix}
        b\\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and solve for $x_0=A_0^{-1}b_0$. Since $A_0$ is square and of full rank, $x_0$ is a unique solution. Note that the equation $A_0x_0=b_0$ explicitly specifies that $Ax_0=b$ and $v_1^Tx_0=v_2^Tx_0=0$. Obviously, $x_0$ is not in the null space of $A$ and $A(cv_1+dv_2)=\mathbf0$.

In summary, all the solutions to $Ax=b$ can be expressed as $x=x_0+cv_1+dv_2$ where $x_0$ is unique (at least in the subspace of $A$). This approach could easily be extended to null spaces of higher dimensions.

Comment: Why will x0 be a unique solution?

Comment: @Saad: See revised answer.